# How can I share video/image to snapchat stories in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, snapchat

I want to share video to snapchat but I don't want to use default share(UIActivity controller). When clicked button it should open snapchat stories with chosen video. I tried Snapchat kit but it doesn’t open the app, just brings snapchat website

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {

        let snapshot = imageView.image

        let photo = SCSDKSnapPhoto(image: snapshot!)
        let snap = SCSDKPhotoSnapContent(snapPhoto: photo)
        snap.caption = "Snap on Snapchat!"

        snap.attachmentUrl = "https://www.snapchat.com"

        let api = SCSDKSnapAPI(content: snap)
        
        api.startSnapping { error in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
               

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Check whether the creative kit enabled in your portal. if not then enable it first..